# Prometheus count API calls

Tags: java, prometheus

We are using Prometheus to collect a variety of metrics. We have a requirement where we want to collect information about which API is being called how many times.

One way of doing this is placing a prometheus counter in the API controller class and incrementing this counter.

Is there any other way of doing using another library along with Prometheus ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking? A Prometheus counter from the Java client library is the standard way to do this.

Comment: So lets say my application has three API's. For e.g.                                                           1. GET /userInfo         2. POST /update                                                                                                                                     3 POST /edit                                                                                                                                     I want information which API was called how many times.

Comment: anyone found the answer